# IMAPLib fetch function fails every third try

Tags: python, imaplib

I am having a weird issue where imaplib's fetch function fails every third try. I am selecting a search term from a list of terms, and then using that search term to pull a list of emails containing the term from a gmail mailbox. I'm then selecting a random message, and pulling the line that contains the search term. Every third time I run the script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Spike/python/helloflask/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/Spike/python/helloflask/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1506, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/Users/Spike/python/helloflask/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1504, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/Spike/python/helloflask/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1265, in full_dispatch_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "/Users/Spike/python/helloflask/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1332, in make_response
raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

I've done some testing and printed out the emails and sure enough, the search term is not in there. This means that every third time the script is run, it pulls an email because it contains a search term it does not actually contain. This is mystifying to me. Does anyone know what the heck is going on?

Relevant code:

```
clean2 = [feeling.strip() for feeling in open('feeling2.txt').readlines()] #open the txt file full of feelings from the wefeelfine api
random_feeling = random.choice(clean2) 
print "this is a random feeling", random_feeling
status, numbers_list = s.search(None, '(BODY "%s")' % random_feeling) #searching the mailbox, finding ids with that search term, saving to list
numbers.append(numbers_list) #append the numbers list

smsgids = str(numbers) #turning the numbers list into a string
ids_list = smsgids.strip().split(' ') #splitting it into a list
msg_random = random.choice(ids_list) #pulling a random id from the id list
typ, msg_data = s.fetch(msg_random, '(BODY[TEXT])') #pulling the message and saving it as a variable

soup = BeautifulSoup(repr(msg_data), "html5lib") #turning it into a beautifulsoup object, but as a string first
text = soup.find_all("div") #finding all of the html div tags and saving it as a variable
as_text = [item.text for item in text]
chat_text = '\n'.join(as_text)
print chat_text
for line in as_text:
    print random_feeling
    print line
    if random_feeling in line:
        return line
```

Comment: Given the frequeny with which you're seeing the error and the presence of random.choice(clean2), I'd guess that about one out of three values in feeling2.txt has a problem and that's why you're seeing the intermittent error.